# Question re banked track with no friction. What provides for normal force and why does the car not slide down the banked track?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

See attached figure[image: Cross section of banked track]

1. when finding normal force Fn, why do we get two different answers depending on if you use resolved mg force or Fn?
   $Fn = mg cos \theta\; and\; 
      $Fn cos\theta$ = mg$
2. what is opposing $mg sin\theta$ on a frictionless surface?, why does the car not slide down the banked road like an object on the inclined plane?

I feel it has something to do with using more than one co-ordinated axes simultaneously? It still does not make intuitive sense to me. I apologize if it is too fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We *assume* that the car is traveling at a speed $v$ that prevents it from sliding down despite there being no friction.

   The car's net acceleration (i.e., the centripetal acceleration as it traverses a circular path) is in the horizontal direction. A component of the normal force provides this centripetal acceleration. $\displaystyle F_n\sin\theta=m\frac{v^2}{r}$ ------ (1).

   So, the car's net acceleration in the vertical direction is zero.

   So, we can write $F_n\cos\theta-mg=0\implies\displaystyle F_n=\frac{mg}{\cos\theta}$

   Substituting for $F_n$ in (1), we get

   $\displaystyle mg\tan\theta=m\frac{v^2}{r}$

   $v=\sqrt{rg\tan\theta}$

   Your equation $F_n-mg\cos\theta=0$ is incorrect as the net acceleration in the direction of the normal force is nonzero.

---

2. The equation $mg\sin\theta=ma$ would be wrong because, by assumption, the car's net acceleration is in the horizontal direction, not the incline's direction.

Comment: i get your answer to the first question. For the second part, my question in other words was,  why is the car not sliding down the track by the unopposed force $mgsin\theta$ as it is frictionless?

Comment: Well, the net acceleration in the direction of the incline _is_ nonzero.

Comment: so, if there is net non zero acceleration in a direction, then there does not always to have a motion in that direction? it kind of makes sense and also does not.

Comment: When a particle moves on a curved path, as in this case, its acceleration _cannot_ be tangent to the path. The _velocity_ is tangent to the path, though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).